# Image is lost items when export from *.ai file to *.svg file in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: svg, vector, adobe-illustrator

I have a problem when export from *.ai file to *.svg file. When I used web browser to view *.svg file, image is not correct ( Leaf vein is lost ). 
 See image below:

[image]

**Environment:** 
OS: Windows 10, Mac OS 10.14.2 
Illustrator: Adobe Illustrator CC 2019
Original AI file: [lost_item_test.ai](https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/lost_item_test.zip)
Exported SVG file: [lost_item_test.svg](https://futushigame.firebaseapp.com/lost_item_test.svg)

Select File -> Save as ... --> choose SVG ( svg ) --> click button "save" 
SVG options dialog choose option like attach image. 
click "OK" to save to SVG file

**Expected:** 
Display in SVG is the same with AI editor

**Actual:** 
+ SVG is lost or invisible some objects ( Leaf vein is lost )

Here is my export Option: 
[image]

Please help me resolve this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit around with the code and noticed that there is a `styles` section in the svg. when i start deleting some of the styles in there the veins start showing up again. i think there are some styles that the browsers dont seem to support? 
i'd recommend looking into those styles and maybe the colors.

there is also a series on https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/ i'd scroll around to see if there is one that you perhaps could use!

Comment: Thank you @Yilmaz, are you talking about some styles like: **.st1{fill:#6F6D3D;adobe-blending-mode:normal;}** , **.st3{adobe-blending-mode:lighten;}**, is there any way to make Internet Browser recognize these styles? or mapping between these styles to equivalent styles which are supported in all browsers ?

Comment: Yes i was indeed talking about those. When i started deleting some i noticed the veins started to appear again. But i wouldnt know how to get a browser to recognize that